# Finding the limit of an expression involving two Lerch transcendent functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, special-functions

Consider the following expression:
$$
f(s) = s^{n+1} \, \Phi(s^2,1,-1-\epsilon) - s^3 \Phi \left(s^2,1,-\frac{n}{2}-\epsilon \right)  \, , 
$$
where $\Phi$ is the Lerch transcendent function (implemented in Maple as LerchPhi). Here $s \in [0,1]$.
I was wondering whether there exists a technique  that allows the analytical evaluation of the limit of $f(s)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Actually, it can be shown that this emerges in the evaluation of the sum 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \frac{s^{2k+3}}{\frac{n}{2}-k}
= s^{n+1} + \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} f(s) \, ,
$$
where $n$ is an even integer.

Any help or hints are most welcome!

Comment: Have you tried to use the series definition of the Lerch transcendent?

Comment: @YuriyS This eventually leads to divisions by zero -- i think

Comment: Just for clarification: does the $e$ denotes Euler's number or just a variable since you are talking about $e\to0$?

Comment: @mrtaurho $e$ is just a variable -- i will change that notation now

Comment: Is the question about how to get the finite sum starting from the expression for $f(s)$? Essentially this is just a repeated application of the identity $\Phi(z, s, a) = z \Phi(z, s, a + 1) + a^{-s}$.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks for the comment -- here the goal is to provide the limit of $f(s)$ as  $\epsilon \to 0$. Apparently the function is singular for $\epsilon=0$. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What I mean is I'm not sure whether the goal is to prove your second formula (which then answers the question about the limit) or to find a closed form for the sum. The change of variables $k = n/2 - k$ will give a difference of two sums of $s^{-2k}/k$ and therefore a difference of two Lerch transcendents with $z > 1$, which is a closed form but isn't much simpler than the finite sum that you have.

Comment: @Maxim Here $f(s)$ needs to be expressed in term of LerchPhi (not a sum) and without $\epsilon$. It would be helpful if you could post an answer so that i can clearly see what you mean -- thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$f(s) = s^{n + 1} \sum_{k \geq n/2 - 1}
  \frac {s^{2 (k - n/2 + 1)}} {k - n/2 - \epsilon} -
 s^3 \sum_{k \geq 0}
  \frac {s^{2 k}} {k - n/2 - \epsilon} = \\
-\sum_{0 \leq k < n/2 - 1} \frac {s^{2 k + 3}} {k - n/2 - \epsilon}
\xrightarrow {\epsilon \to 0}
\sum_{0 \leq k < n/2 - 1} \frac {s^{2 k + 3}} {n/2 - k}.$$
A closed form can be obtained by using the identity
$$\Phi(z, 1, a) =
\frac 1 z \Phi \!\left( \frac 1 z, 1, 1 - a \right) +
\pi (-z)^{-a} \csc \pi a, \\
|z| > 1, \;a \notin \mathbb Z$$
and then passing to the limit, which gives
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f(s) =
s^{n - 1} \Phi \!\left(\frac 1 {s^2}, 1, 2 \right) -
 s \Phi \!\left( \frac 1 {s^2}, 1, \frac n 2 + 1 \right).$$

Comment: Fantastic answer -- thanks a lot for helping. It works!